# Razor/Mvc4 web page bad redirection of Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Well i'm new here, i'll try to be clear.

I'm making a forum with Razor/Mvc4, the problem is when i try to use this:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(@elemento.nombre, "Temas", "Categorias", new { id = @i, onclick = 
 "javascript:IdCat(this)" })
```

I don't know why but when i press the link it redirects me to Home/Temas and i want to go Categorias/Tema.

In my project i have two controllers, HomeController and CategoriasController, i think everything is ok, but it keeps redirecting to Home/Temas.

```
public class CategoriasController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Temas()
    {
        Session["user_name"] = Session["user_name"];
        Session["IDG"] = Session["IDG"];
        Session["ID"] = Session["ID"];

        Tema tem = new Tema();
        List<Tema> temas = new List<Tema>(); 
        temas = tem.ObtenerTemasPorCategoriaID(int.Parse(Session["idCat"].ToString()));

        Categoria cat = new Categoria();
        ViewBag.NombreCat = cat.obtenerNombreCategoriaById(int.Parse(Session["idCat"].ToString()));

        return View();
    }

}
```

Hopefully someone can help. Many thanks.

Comment: What is the `IdCat` function doing? I would also include the generated link from the view.

Comment: I'm trying to take the id from the link.

Comment: Yes, but **what** do you do in your JavaScript? Unless you interrupt the default action (a GET request), your script will never have a chance to run. If you're just trying to use the `id` value, change your controller to `public ActionResult Temas(string id="")` and read it from there.

Comment: This is the javascript. I don't know if works.                                                                <script  type="text/javascript">
            function getMyID(inputId) {
                Session["idCat"] = inputId;
            };
        </script>

Comment: That's not going to work. You're mixing client code and server code.

Comment: I need that id. Some ideas?

Comment: I already mentioned how to fix it. Read the comments above.

Comment: But Html.ActionLink is just a link, how can i send the id with it? (i'm new with C# / Razor).

Comment: Hyperlinks are GET requests. If you add an optional parameter to you action that matches the parameter you specified in the ActionLink helper, the model binder will bind it correctly.

Comment: Finally i understand it. I really do not know how to thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overload of the `Html.ActionLink` that you are using is incorrect for a couple of reasons.

First, the onclick is not a RouteValueParameter and actually should be in the HtmlAttributes portion of the `Html.ActionLink`.  Second, I think the overload you are actually looking for is (note the controller will be moved to the Object routevalues parameter):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

With all this said, the correct syntax should be:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(elemento.nombre, "Temas", new { controller="Categorias", nid = i}, new {onclick = = "javascript:IdCat(this)" })
```

If you are still having issues, I think you should consider examining your route definitions to ensure you are not routing incorrectly. Also, the javascript could be causing an issue as well and without seeing the JavaScript code, it may be hard to say.  I see above that you are setting a Session variable with JavaScript (which won't work because one is client side and one is server side - and Session is completely server side).  You should be able to set the session in the "Temas" ActionResult without having to use JavaScript.

A full list of the available `Html.ActionLink()` overloads are [available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492124%28v=vs.118%29.aspx).
**EDIT**

You are sending the Id, but your ActionResult method isn't looking for it.  Change your ActionResult in your controller to the following(note that we have added the nid you are passing from the ActionLink to the parameters of the function):

```
public ActionResult Temas(int nid)
    {
    Session["user_name"] = Session["user_name"];
    Session["IDG"] = Session["IDG"];
    Session["ID"] = Session["ID"];

    Tema tem = new Tema();
    List<Tema> temas = new List<Tema>(); 
    temas = tem.ObtenerTemasPorCategoriaID(nid);

    Categoria cat = new Categoria();
    ViewBag.NombreCat = cat.obtenerNombreCategoriaById(nid);

    return View();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I use your code, but as you said, my javascript doesn't work and i don't know how to send the id. ¿Can you help me please?

Comment: @Nameless999 - my edit should help get you a little closer (and eliminate the JavaScript on this ActionLink).  Why are you setting session variables to themselves in the first three lines?

Comment: I'm learning c# and razor. This is my firts web page with this lenguaje and i was trying to do something hahaha. I'll try your solution, thanks.

Comment: @Nameless999 - Good deal - the best way to learn is to go and do.  Good luck with your web app!

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one your Razor syntax is incorrect.  You should NOT include the `@` escape prefix when referencing variables in the `@Html.ActionLink()` helper call:

```
 @Html.ActionLink(elemento.nombre, "Temas", "Categorias", new { id = i, onclick = 
 "javascript:IdCat(this)" })
```

The only time an `@` would be valid is if you were escaping a keyword, as in `@class = someClass`.

Also, you should realize that the `onclick` call *may* override your link.  The `onclick` function will execute *prior* to following the hyperlink. The link will be followed *only if the function returns `true`*  If the function returns `false`, *the link will not be followed!*

Comment: Peter, prefixing identifiers with `@` is *always* legal.  It is merely that it is not *helpful* unless the identifier is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
       @Html.ActionLink(@elemento.nombre, "Temas", "Categorias",  new { id = @i} ,new{onclick = "javascript:IdCat(this)" })
```

cheers